# Firebase Authentication and State Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, state, firebase-authentication

I am a student learning React. I am trying to create a web app where a user must sign in with Google before viewing any of the content. I began with the code from the `github-notetaker` example and have edited `Main.js`. So far, I am writing the entire logic inside the `init()` method and setting `loggedIn` and `email` values in `this.state`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { RouteHandler } from 'react-router';
import Rebase from 're-base';

class Main extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: props.loggedIn,
      email: props.email
    };
  }

  authDataCallback(authData) {
    if (authData) {
      console.log('User is already logged in.');
      console.log(authData["google"]["email"]); // works as expected
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: true,
        email: authData["google"]["email"]
      });
      console.log(this.state.email); // does not work as expected
    } else {

      this.setState({
        loggedIn: false
      });
      console.log('Attempting to authenticate user account');
      this.ref.authWithOAuthPopup('google', function (error, authData) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Login Failed!', error);
        } else {
          console.log('Authenticated successfully');
        }
      }, {
        scope: "email"
      });
    }
  }
  init(){
    console.log('Init called');
    this.ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/');
    this.ref.onAuth(this.authDataCallback.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillMount(){
      this.router = this.context.router;
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.init();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    this.init();
  }
  render(){
    if (!this.state.loggedIn) {
      return (
        <div className="main-container">
          <div className="container">
            <h3>You are not authenticated. <a href="">Login</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="main-container">
          <div className="container">
            <RouteHandler {...this.props}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
};
Main.propTypes = {
  loggedIn: React.PropTypes.bool,
  email: React.PropTypes.string
};
Main.defaultProps = {
  loggedIn: false,
  email: ''
}
Main.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
export default Main;
```

I am encountering an odd bug and believe that I am doing this the wrong way. When the user authenticates successfully, all of the information is saved and the user's `email` is written. Here's what the console log looks like:

`User is already logged in.
address@email.com // corresponds to authData["google"]["email"]
address@email.com // corresponds to this.state.email = CORRECT!!`

However, when I refresh the page, the new print looks like this, and it appears that the email and object are still available to me but are not getting saved in `this.state`.

`User is already logged in.
address@email.com // corresponds to authData["google"]["email"]
null`

I am currently learning React and so this may be a really simple error. Thank you so much for your time and help in advance. If you could point me in the right direction or let me a know a better way to do this, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing the code wrong.
`var currentAuthData = this.ref.getAuth();` sends a request to fireBase to get the authentication, however the next line of code `if (currentAuthData) {` is run before fireBase can retrieve the correct information.
You must use a callback function instead.

```
ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);

function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log('User is already logged in.');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me fix this method. I've updated the format to what I think is your suggestion in my original question. However, it still does not work when I refresh the page. I think this has more to do with my constructor overriding the ```this.setState``` part

Comment: Using `onAuth()` is a good approach. But `this.ref.getAuth()` does **not** send a request to Firebase. It instead returns the *current* authentication state of the client. See the [API docs for getAuth()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/getauth.html).

Comment: Yup.  `getAuth()` is synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the reason for my issue. When I call the following code in `render()`

```
<h1> {this.state.email} </h1>
```

It works just fine. Therefore, my conclusion is that `console.log(this.state.email)` is somehow run before `this.setState()` is fully completed.

Comment: setState is asynchronous. So you're correct in that the log will run before setState is finished. You can actually pass a callback into setState to run the specified code when setState is finished. So I'd try that.
this.setState({newState: 'thing'}, function(){console.log(this.state.email)})